# .htaccess conditions: https issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A while ago, I asked a question about some .htaccess rules.
Somebody was really kind and gave me the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force https and non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect /index.htm to /home and avoids infinite redirect loop
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.htm\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /home [R=301,L]

# Rewrite (internally) /home to /index.htm
RewriteRule ^home$ /index.htm [L]

# Redirect (if not an existing file) to /index.htm (which will after redirect to /home)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.htm [R=301,L]
```

I thought it worked perfectly fine, but I have some issues:

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/home  
https://example.com/index.htm 
https://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/home
https://www.example.com/index.htm
```

- all variants redirecting to https://example.com/home working fine

```
http://example.com/ -> https://home (in Chrome) / error (in Firefox)  
http://example.com/home -> https://home (in Chrome) / error (in Firefox)   
http://example.com/index.htm -> https://index.htm  
http://www.example.com/ -> error
http://www.example.com/home -> https://home (in Chrome) / error (in Firefox)    
http://www.example.com/index.htm -> https://index.htm
```

- not working at all

I think it is maybe caused by the [L] flags, but I can not imagine how to solve this problem.

**Thanks for your help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem is in your first rule because you are attempting to capture value from a `RewriteCond` after `OR` clause.

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force https and non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Redirect /index.htm to /home and avoids infinite redirect loop
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.htm\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /home [R=301,L]

# Rewrite (internally) /home to /index.htm
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /index.htm [L,NC]

# Redirect (if not an existing file) to /index.htm (which will after redirect to /home)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /home [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thanks, we're getting closer. `http://www.example.com` and `http://www.example.com/home` are now perfectly redirected to `https://example.com/home`.  
But `http://example.com/` is redirected to `http://example.com/home`, without `https://`.  
Can you tell me how to extend the first rule for that value "no www but https off"?

Comment: The updated rules did not work better - now if I type in an URL without `/home` or `/index.htm`, it does not rename to `/home`, but it is internally redirected an shown. I thought, the problem might be the first rule, because the first line of it refers to any that already has `https://` but `www.` is there and should not, and the following two refers to any that has `http://www.`, so do I need another rule like `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC,OR]` between first and second line? But that seems not to be working...

Comment: Okay, so I want all of these URL variants: 
`https://example.com/`, 
`https://example.com/home`, 
`https://example.com/index.htm`, 
`https://www.example.com/`, 
`https://www.example.com/home`, 
`https://www.example.com/index.htm`, 
`http://example.com/`, 
`http://example.com/home`, 
`http://example.com/index.htm`, 
`http://www.example.com/`, 
`http://www.example.com/home`, 
`http://www.example.com/index.htm`
to be rewritten to `https://example.com/home`.

Comment: **With your first version of rules, it worked for all exept for:**
`http://example.com/`, 
`http://example.com/home`, 
`http://example.com/index.htm`, 
which have no "www", like I want, but don't use https (which should be rewritten).

I want every non-file to be redirected, because of some former URLs, that are not used anymore. 
So the visitor should be redirected from every possible URL to the landing page at "/home"